# python different slashes based upon operating system

Tags: python

I often find myself in the situation where I am constructing a path to output a csv or other file on different operating systems.

Thus, when building the path, I often find myself doing something like:

```
if sys.platform == "win32":
    slashes = "\\"
elif sys.platform == "linux" or sys.platform == "darwin":
    slashes = "/"
else:
    slashes= "ERROR"
```

Then I have something like:

```
destinationpath = mypath + "slashes" + myfile.
```

Is there a python way to automatically handle this such as a predefined parameter that automatically selects the right slash type?

Thank you!

Comment: It's better to use `os.path.join` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `os.path.join()` on the components of the filename; it knows whether to use forward slashes or backslashes.

```
>>> mypath = "foo"
>>> myfile = "bar.ext"
>>> os.path.join( mypath, myfile) 
'foo/bar.ext'
>>> os.path.join( "many", "path", "components", "beforethefile.ext" )
'many/path/components/beforethefile.ext'
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple, just do the following

```
import os
slashes = os.sep
```

Although, you should use `os.path.join()` instead of playing with the path strings yourself. The builtin knows what to use as correctly pointed out by Russell in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19782459/2689986).

Comment: This doesn't work. It gives me an ";" vs an ":". I need it to be a "\\" vs a "/". Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: It's `os.sep`, not `os.pathsep`. But use `os.path.join()`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Corrected accordingly. Thanks for the kind pointing out.